# Image not loading with universal image loader

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, universal-image-loader, image-loading

I am using [Universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
for loading images and showing them in a `ListView`.
Some of the links I have are with the image extension like this

```
Link 1 : http://HOST/staticContent/EnlgImg250x250/HandBags-ContemporarydesignblackClutch-HB1122-1.jpg

Link 2 : http://HOST/images/get/Product/9958/1
```

both the links show image in the web browser but the images are not loading in my app using the `Image loader`

I am using the following code :

```
imagLoader.displayImage(imagUrl, imageView ,displayOptions);
```

can someone help me with this please?

Comment: There's not really enough infor to answer this. Do you get any errors in the Log? Can you show us some more code?

Comment: @billynomates  There is nothing to show in log?
The image simply doesn't load with link 2.

Comment: What so link 1 does but link 2 doesn't?

Comment: @billynomates link 1 gives the image path with .jpg extension but link 2 simply gives a path without the image extension

Comment: But if you try to load the image using UIL and Link 1, the image is displayed? But with Link 2, the image is not displayed?

Comment: @billynomates yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by downloading the latest version of `UIL` from [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). I was using a older version `jar` file in my project.

Answer (score 1):

android-query-full.0.26.7.jar download this library and use

AQuery aQur = new AQuery(context);
aQur.id(imageView).progress(progress).image(list.get(position).toString());